# Sticky footer with sticky header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make sticky footer with sticky header?

Everything works great but when I apply sticky header I need to make `body { padding-top: 60px; }` for it to not overlap with content. The problem then is that my footer goes down below the page.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFpDG/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">STICKY HEADER</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">STICKY FOOTER</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body, .wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  /* for sticky footer to not go below page */
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* for sticky header to not overlap content */
}
.push, .footer {
  height: 60px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add `padding-top: 60px;` to `.content` instead of `.wrap`?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFpDG/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have myself been looking into this problem. I have seen quite a few solutions and each of them had issues, often involving some magic numbers.

So using best practices from various sources I came up with this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfSM3/248/

The thing i wanted to achieve specifically here was to get the main content to scroll between footer and header inside green area.

here is simple css:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
header {
  height: 4em;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.content {
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:5em;
  bottom:5em;
  overflow:auto;
}
  .contentinner {

}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: -4em 0 -2em 0;
  background:green;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}
 footer {
   height: 2em;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```