# Having issues for a responsive fixed header and sticky footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having issues to fix the header. I already manage to make the footer sticky and responsive, now I want the header to be **fixed** and responsive  for different screen size.
This is what I tried so far:

*Live Demo* http://jsbin.com/vevay/1/edit?html,css,output

**HTML** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Responsive Sticky Footer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
<body class="container"> 
    <div class="block header_block">
        <h1>Responsive Fixed Header</h1> 
    </div>


    <div class="block push body_block">
        <h2>Body Content</h2> 

    </div> 

    <div class="block footer_block">
        <h2>Responsive The Sticky Footer</h2> 
        <h1>cool</h1>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** code

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.block {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}

.push {
    height: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block:nth-child(odd) { 
}

.header_block{
    background: grey;
}

.body_block{
    background: lightblue;
 }

.footer_block{
        background: green;

}
```

*update:*

I did some researcher before posting this question, their are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324402/sticky-footer-with-sticky-header?rq=1) but the footer is not responsive, that's why I posted this question.

**EDIT**

I've come up with another solution : http://jsbin.com/gevafi/2/edit but I still have a margin left at the bottom of the footer.

**EDIT 2**

Temporary solution: http://jsbin.com/vokiqi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: When I resize the output window of your jsbin, the content all resizes just fine, sooooo I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I want the header to be fixed while scrolling

Comment: Usually you just set the position to fixed for the header. But you're going to struggle a bit because you're using tables.

Comment: @chdltest I tried a fixed position but it didn't work

Comment: I've added a new solution for your sticky footer by editing my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to have mercy on you and create one from scratch for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yo2ukrua/3/

Instead of using tables, I removed all of it and kept them as blocks. For your setup, you didn't really need any tables and I'm guessing you only used it so that you could make your footer stick to the bottom.

Once they're back to blocks, you can just give the footer and header a fixed position, set the footer to bottom and header to top.

Then apply a top and bottom margin to the body and the margin should be the height of the footer and header.

CSS:

```
.header_block {
      background: grey;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0px;
}

    .body_block {
      background: lightblue;
      margin-bottom: 18px; /* height of your footer */
      margin-top: 18px; /* height of your header */
     }

    .footer_block {
      background: green;
      bottom: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body class="container"> 
  <div class="block header_block">
    <h1>Responsive Fixed Header</h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="block push body_block">
    <h2>Body Content<br>Body Content<br>Body Content <br>Body Content <br>Body Content<br>Body Content<br>Body Content<br>Body Content</h2> 
  </div> 
  <div class="block footer_block">
    <h2>Responsive The Sticky Footer</h2> 
    <h1>cool</h1>  
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**Alternatively, you can have a better footer**

http://jsfiddle.net/yo2ukrua/15/

It uses a div (push) that has a minimum height of the window size but if the window size is smaller than the content (creating a scroll) it then uses the height of the content itself, thus always pushing the footer to the bottom. The footer also retains a position of relative.

Comment: Thanks for deciding to have mercy on me :) . I just tested your solution which I stumble up  on just before posting this here. The problem with this solution is that the footer is always fixed at the bottom. In other words, the footer is always visible. That's not what I want. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Then you have other options to tackle that. You can either set your footer as absolute instead of fixed and then use JS to set it as relative if the screen is too small in terms of height. The next would be to set it as relative and give body/html a 100% height then applying height 100% to a div.

Comment: I don't want use JS for this. I've come up with this http://jsbin.com/gevafi/1/edit?html,css,output but their is a margin left at bottom of the footer

Comment: OK, I don't know how jsfiddle is displaying your edited solution but this is not working. I downloaded the code, test it on chrome and firefox but it is not working (the footer). Did you test this with your browser without jsfiddle?

Comment: The jsfiddle is using normalizer stylesheet which you should have (it's a reset to make all browsers to be as similar as they can with each other).

Other than that, careful with the divs and classes. I moved a few things around. Also, let me know if the solution in the latest jsfiddle was correct. (just to make sure, it's this link http://jsfiddle.net/yo2ukrua/15/ )

Comment: How can I download the JSFiddle code with the normalised css?

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ download it there. I assume you know how to put that in your header.

Comment: Here is the whole code, with Normalize included. but it still don't work. http://jsbin.com/yojavurihu/1/edit?html,css,output Did you try this localy without jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/caxobuvufi/1/edit?html,css,output it's because you have different font sizes and margins...

Comment: Try to add more content in the footer. it's don't work. check this http://jsbin.com/vokiqi/1/edit

Comment: I'll stick to this to this solution till I find a better one http://jsbin.com/vokiqi/1/edit?html,css,output . Thank you very much.