# Footer above bottom of page, instead of being at the bottom of the page content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the footer stay at the bottom of the page, NOT the bottom of the screen (fixed) but at the bottom of the entire page, so you can only see it after scrolling to bottom. However, for some reason it stays above the bottom, and I can't seem to find the reason...
FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/okfudezn/

Image:
[image]

HTML (the div has no wrappers etc):

```
<div class="footer">
        <a>REGISTERED NAMES AND TRADEMARKS ARE THE PROPERTY OF THEIR RESPECTIVE OWNERS - Copyright © 2017 All rights reserved</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #4b4c46;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e1dac5;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: can you share fiddle or codepen link

Comment: Posible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okfudezn/

Comment: @Troyer checked it, didn't help

Comment: @SuperUser added it ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky footer with sticky header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324402/sticky-footer-with-sticky-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change replace you content div height to auto
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okfudezn/1/)

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: But how can I make the div smaller now?.... since it sticks out like hell at the bottom

Comment: You have used `top: -100` & `margin-bottom: 80px;` in content css, just remove it

Comment: You can also remove height from grid class

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That puts it at the screen bottom, not the page bottom you know?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```css
html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  min-height: calc(100% - 54px);
  padding-top: 54px; /* Header & Footer */
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background: red;
}

#content {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  position: absolut;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background: yellow;
}

.simulateContent {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    CONTENT START
    <div class="simulateContent"></div>
    CONTENT END
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man I clearly said I don't need the fixed screen position but the footer to stay at THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE... :|

Answer (score 0):

Change this css

```
.content {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    /*height: 650px;*/ /*Remove this*/
    margin: 0 auto 30px;/*Change this*/
    overflow: hidden;/*Add this*/
    position: relative;
    /*top: -100px;*//*Remove this*/
    width: 650px;
}
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    /*height: 1000px;*/ /*Remove this*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okfudezn/